# Rotating comet around planet

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a simple game. Tell me how to make object (comet) fly and rotate around orbit of another object (planet). I could only make the comet turn and fly toward the planet, but it is necessary that when a certain distance is reached, the comet starts to rotate around the planet’s orbit.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P5jZ.png)

```
this.mesh.translateZ(this.speed);

if (this.target.position.distanceTo(this.mesh.position) >= 100) {
    let targetQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    let rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotationMatrix.lookAt(this.mesh.position, this.target.position, this.mesh.up);
    targetQuaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix);

    if (!this.mesh.quaternion.equals(targetQuaternion)) {
        let step = 0.01;
        this.mesh.quaternion.rotateTowards(targetQuaternion, step);
    }
} else {
    //how to make a comet(this.mesh) fly around the orbit of the planet(this.target)?
}
```

Comment: Well, what have you done so far?

Comment: well, for now the comet is only flying to the planet:)

Comment: Hi Alex. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) where you can get tips about how to make your question more likely to receive answers. Right now, your question is missing a lot of context. I recommend creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using Stack Snippets so we can debug what you have and get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make one object orbit another is to utilize parent-child relationships. If you add a child to an object it shares a transformation, so when the parent is rotated the child is rotated with it  - and when the child has a large translation offset, it effectively "orbits" the parent.

Very simple example of this:

```
init() {
    this.planet = new Mesh(new SphereBufferGeometry(100))
    this.satellite = new Mesh(new SphereBufferGeometry(5))
    this.satelliteCenter = new Object3D()

    this.satellite.position.set(1000,0,0)
    this.satelliteCenter.add(this.satellite)

    this.scene.add(this.planet)
    this.scene.add(this.satelliteCenter)
}

update() {
    this.satelliteCenter.rotateY(Math.PI / 2000) // one full revolution every 1000 frames
}
```